# Unable to Reach Internet from Private Ec2 with NAT Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, network-programming, ping, bastion-host

I am unable to ping google.com from my private EC2 instance in my AWS VPC.

I have a bastion set up in front of the private instance, and am connecting to it via guacamole. But once I login and run `ping google.com`, it hangs.

[image]

My security group inbound / outbound rules for the bastion look like:

[image]

And here are the inbound / outbound rules for the private instance:

[image]

My Network ACLs are wide open. I have a private route table that points to the Network Gateway for any destination. I also have a public route table that points to the Internet Gateway for any destination. What am I missing? Why can't I ping google from my private EC2 instance?

Comment: As your are running IP4. Do you have a NAT Gateway / NAT instance? Is the default route of the private subnet to the NAT Gateway, and does the NAT Gateway have a route to the internet (0.0.0.0/0) via the Internet Gateway?

Comment: Checkout the following video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yl81_rXbbgA

Comment: Since you can connect to the bastion host, I assume there's no problem with the IGW. Is the route table with the NAT gateway correctly associated with your private subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally associated my private subnet with my public route table. After I changed the association to the private route table with the nat gateway, it worked!